# Custom Post Types Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

estoy usando Custom Post Types y me gustaria saber como puedo quitar el Add de un post pero solo del menu. He probado con esto:

```
'capabilities' => array(
   'create_posts' => false
 ),
```

Pero esto tambien me borra el que hay dentro del All.

Gracias

Comment: Para poder ayudarte necesitaría más información. El código lo estás añadiendo en el header o en el function? Podrías agregar más parte del código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes agregar esta función en tu plugin o la pagina de funciones de la plantilla. 
Recuerda cambiar $post_type por el nombre de tu custom Post Type.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_136058_remove_menu_pages' );

function wpse_136058_remove_menu_pages() {

    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=$post_type' );
    remove_menu_page( $post_type );
}
```